# Google Places Reviews - profile_photo_url field doesn't work

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

Is it possible to display the profile photo of a reviewer about a location he visited in Android?

I mean can I get a valid Http URL based on **profile_photo_url** field?

If you try to paste that URL from profile_photo_url in the browser you'll get an HTTP 404 response.

Is there an API that converts the below URL into a valid one or how does it work?

```
{
  "author_name": "Bogdan Rusu",
  "author_url": "https:\/\/www.google.com\/maps\/contrib\/108255483707161638432\/reviews",
  "language": "en",
  "profile_photo_url": "https:\/\/lh6.googleusercontent.com\/-dQ5fh34ouJk\/AAAAAAAAAAI\/AAAAAAAAAAA\/ACHi3rf_188gKXMwcBh9oJI9HSzYX8Ratg\/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba4\/photo.jpg",
  "rating": 5,
  "relative_time_description": "2 months ago",
  "text": "A very beautiful monastery with a lot of history and old age. It is currently underway, or the rendition of the monasteries. I recommend the surroundings.",
  "time": 1553956652
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all the `\` from the URL.

original:

```
https:\/\/lh6.googleusercontent.com\/-dQ5fh34ouJk\/AAAAAAAAAAI\/AAAAAAAAAAA\/ACHi3rf_188gKXMwcBh9oJI9HSzYX8Ratg\/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba4\/photo.jpg
```

[working](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-dQ5fh34ouJk/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACHi3rf_188gKXMwcBh9oJI9HSzYX8Ratg/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba4/photo.jpg):

```
https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-dQ5fh34ouJk/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/ACHi3rf_188gKXMwcBh9oJI9HSzYX8Ratg/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba4/photo.jpg
```